# Custom Swipe event interfering with default Fling

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom Swipe event on a ListView that is supposed to trigger when I swipe from left-to-right or right-to-left. I've got that neat and working, but there's a catch: the Fling event that happens naturally when I'm trying to scroll now doesn't take effect anymore (I'll explain later). How do I manually recreate the Fling event? The code I'm using is as follows:

The Swipe class:

```
public class Swipe implements SwipeInterface {

public Swipe() {}

@Override
public void bottom2top(View v) {
    //Help!
}

@Override
public void left2right(View v) {
    //Does logic here
}

@Override
public void right2left(View v) {
    //Does logic here
}

@Override
public void top2bottom(View v) {
    //Help!
}

}
```

A custom Detector class. This class mainly checks the distance of the swipe:

```
public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
private Swipe swipe;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 200;
private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

public ActivitySwipeDetector(Swipe swipe) {
    this.swipe = swipe;
}

public void onRightToLeftSwipe(View v) {
    Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
    swipe.right2left(v);
}

public void onLeftToRightSwipe(View v) {
    Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
    swipe.left2right(v);
}

public void onTopToBottomSwipe(View v) {
    Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
    swipe.top2bottom(v);
}

public void onBottomToTopSwipe(View v) {
    Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
    swipe.bottom2top(v);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        downX = event.getX();
        downY = event.getY();
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        upX = event.getX();
        upY = event.getY();

        float deltaX = downX - upX;
        float deltaY = downY - upY;

        // swipe horizontal?
        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
            // left or right
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                this.onLeftToRightSwipe(v);
                return true;
            }
            if (deltaX > 0) {
                this.onRightToLeftSwipe(v);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
        }

        // swipe vertical?
        if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
            // top or down
            if (deltaY < 0) {
                this.onTopToBottomSwipe(v);
                return true;
            }
            if (deltaY > 0) {
                this.onBottomToTopSwipe(v);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
        }
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And finally, this is what I do to implement the custom listener:

```
Swipe swipe = new Swipe();
ActivitySwipeDetector detector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(swipe);
listview.setOnTouchListener(detector);
```

Again, it works beautifully, and I can still implement an OnItemClickListener on the ListView, but it doesn't do any "fling scrolls" anymore because of the overriden bottom2top and top2bottom methods in the Swipe class. So the question is how do I "create" the Fling scroll again? My guess is that I'll have to replace the code I have labelled as "Help!" with something, but I can't find out what.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) to detect swipe actions.

Comment: Would that fix the problem? Mine is actually an example I found online, so I implemented it first. Is there no way to replicate Flings using my method?

Comment: @Wakka02 I dont sure. But i used [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and method [onFling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent, android.view.MotionEvent, float, float)) to detects swipe gesture, and it works fine for me. But in your example you can try to return false istead of true in method onTouch() after calling your swipe methods.

Comment: D'oh, of course that would have been the easiest solution. Selected as correct answer for the comment, return false will simply pull out of the listener and go back to the default. Thanks mate!